# Type of expression "[" is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, struct

I have searched "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" but none of the instances are helping me figure out my issue.

```
struct Ouid {
    let uid: String
}

public var completion: (Ouid) -> (Void)?
    var results = [Ouid]()



 func noteIsHere() {

    let safetyEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: otherUserEmail)
    
    let recentUIDObserve = ref.child("\(safetyEmail)/uid")
    
    recentUIDObserve.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else {
            return
        }
        
        print("this is value: \(String(describing: value))")

        
        let results: [Ouid] = value.compactMap({ dictionary in
            guard let uid = dictionary**[**"uid"] else {  // for some reason, the "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" highlights at the bracket. 
            
                return nil
            }
        })
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong because I tried to call data from firebase using the compactMap in another view controller and it worked.

This is the code that worked and has no errors:

```
struct Users {
    let name: String
    let email: String
}

public var completion: ((Users) -> (Void))?

func usersAreHere() {

    let recentUserQuery = (ref?.child("user").queryLimited(toFirst: 11))!
    print("recentuserquery: \(recentUserQuery)")
    recentUserQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: String]] else {
           return
        }     
        
        print("\(value)")
        let results: [Users] = value.compactMap({ dictionary in
            guard let name = dictionary["name"]?.lowercased(),
                  let safeEmail = dictionary["email"] else {
                            return nil
                        }
 
            return Users(name: name, email: safeEmail)
        })
        self.results = results
        
        
        self.results.shuffle()
        

        self.tableView.reloadData()      
        
    })       
    
    self.results.append(contentsOf: results)
            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compactMap will query all elements of an Array.

```
guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else {
    return
}
```

As you can see, **value** is a **String**, so when you use **value.compactMap({ dictionary in }**, it will query all the elements of "value". "dictionary" is Character type(String is array of Character), not Dictionary. You can not use [].

In the 2nd example:

```
guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: String]] else {
   return
}
```

**value** now is an Array of Dictionary ([[String: String]] == Array<[String: String]>), so when you use **value.compactMap({ dictionary in }**, "dictionary" is Dictionary type. Now you can use value["key"] to get the value

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding this: ""dictionary" is Character type(String is array of Character), not Dictionary. You can not use []". What can I use then?

Comment: Hi @personalproblem, if you want to get the "uid" in a dictionary, you should use the same way in 2nd example that parse the snapshot.value to [[String: String]]